# Updating a Spinner With data from Async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

On the launch of the application i want to populate a spinner in a fragment with data from a database. I'm pulling a list of string from a database and want to display it in a spinner. I've got the list to populate and i believe the ArrayAdapter is changed in PostExecute but when when nothing is displayed.

Fragment Code

```
 public static class RegisterFragment extends Fragment{


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     List<String> instituteList = new ArrayList<String>();
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    if (instituteList.isEmpty()){ //list is null on app start-up
        Log.d("test","null list");
    }else{

    Spinner autoInstitute = (Spinner)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.institute);
// Get the string array
    String[] institutes =  (String[]) instituteList.toArray(new String[instituteList.size()]);;
// Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
ArrayAdapter<String> instituteApapdter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, institutes);
instituteApapdter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    autoInstitute.setAdapter(instituteApapdter);
    }
       return rootView;
}
```

Async Class

```
class getInstitute extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Institute List");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                  //Get data and store in List
    }
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        institutes_array =  (String[]) instituteList.toArray(new String[instituteList.size()]);;
        final ArrayAdapter<String> instituteApapdter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(Login.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, institutes_array);
        instituteApapdter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                instituteApapdter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        //autoInstitute.setAdapter(instituteApapdter); // causes nullpointerexception   
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem a bit more.

Comment: So you are updating your `instituteList` in `doInBackground`?

Comment: yeah instituteList is updated in doInBackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
Spinner autoInstitute = (Spinner)rootView. findViewById(R.id.institute);
```

in place of this :

```
Spinner autoInstitute = (Spinner)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.institute);
```

Also, in your AsyncTask Class, you have written `Login.this` as first argument of `ArrayAdapter()` constructor . Change it to `getActivity()`

**This should be your complete RegisterFragment class:**

```
package com.bhavit.stackoverflow;

public static class RegisterFragment extends Fragment{

    Spinner autoInstitute;
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         List<String> instituteList = new ArrayList<String>();
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);

         if (instituteList.isEmpty()){ //list is null on app start-up
            Log.d("test","null list");
        }else{

        autoInstitute = (Spinner)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.institute);

        GetInstitute obj = new GetInstitute();
        obj.execute();


        }
           return rootView;
    }


     class GetInstitute extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Institute List");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                          //Get data and store in List
            }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                pDialog.dismiss();
                institutes_array =  (String[]) instituteList.toArray(new String[instituteList.size()]);;
                final ArrayAdapter<String> instituteApapdter = 
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, institutes_array);
                instituteApapdter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    instituteApapdter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            autoInstitute.setAdapter(instituteApapdter); // causes nullpointerexception   

            }
     }

}
```

Comment: the 'getActivity()' just tells me no method found

Comment: write RegisterFragment.this.getActivity()

Comment: sorry but 
No enclosing instance of the type Login.RegisterFragment is accessible in scope

Comment: Your Asynctask class must be an innerclass of RegisterFragment. Copy paste your asynctask class and paste it within the RegisterFragment class.